# Why I cannot Analyse Stastics A synonm table?

Tags: oracle

Okay a synonym table means it point to another database, its now owned from the current database, it just a mirror, even its case sensetive ,if I grant select I can select from the other database, I understand that. but why I cannot analyse statistics for this synonym. I need some technical explanation or an official document

Comment: Are you trying to gather statistics for the synonym itself (which wouldn't make much sense), or to the table it points to; and is that actually in the same database (but another schema) or a different database (via a database link)? Including the statements you tried and the errors you got might be helpful too. (A couple of the answers already posted probably explain this anyway, but it would still be good to narrow it down?)

Comment: @AlexPoole a dev was runing Analyse statement on a synonym table ( this table is referred to another database on the same server) the error was ofcourse table is not exists; I was trying to explain in a technical way to make him understand why his doing is wrong. anywya as you pointed the answeres are good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have a look at [Oracle Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_4005.htm#SQLRF01105) which clearly spefices that as a Prerequisites to Analyze any object :

> The schema object to be analyzed must be local, and it must be in your
>   own schema or you must have the ANALYZE ANY system privilege.

Also you must read these:

Restrictions on Analyzing tables is subject to the following restrictions:

•You cannot use ANALYZE to collect statistics on data dictionary tables.

•You cannot use ANALYZE to collect statistics on an external table. Instead, you must use the DBMS_STATS package.

•You cannot use ANALYZE to collect default statistics on a temporary table. However, if you have already created an association between one or more columns of a temporary table and a user-defined statistics type, then you can use ANALYZE to collect the user-defined statistics on the temporary table.

•You cannot compute or estimate statistics for the following column types: REF column types, varrays, nested tables, LOB column types (LOB column types are not analyzed, they are skipped), LONG column types, or object types. However, if a statistics type is associated with such a column, then Oracle Database collects user-defined statistics.

Comment: You should not be using ANALYZE to gather statistics at all. You should use DBMS_STATS()

Comment: Well, firstly i didnot answer whether we should use `ANALYZE ` or not. I just mentioned under which circumstances OP can find failures. Also not all the time `DBMS_STATS` are useful. Please read the doc. It says You must use the ANALYZE statement (rather than DBMS_STATS) for statistics collection not related to the cost-based optimizer. Also i couldnt find if `Analyze` is depreated. So couldnot understand your statement  `You should not be using ANALYZE to gather statistics at all.`

Comment: For the collection of statistics, you should used DBMS_STATS(). ANALYZE is validating structure, such as chained rows, freelist blocks etc.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you will find a document that enumerates all the things you **cannot** do. The doc for `DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS()` is quite clear in that you specify a schema name and a table. 
However, I see see if I can find a technical reason why this may be disallowed.

Comment: This is nt an answer rather it should be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

There is no technical reason why we don't allow the collection of stats via a synonym. We just assume (since that's how it's specified), that the object is a table.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, by "synonym" you are referring to a table in another database that is accessed via a database link.  If that is case, you cannot analyze remote objects over a database link (at least not as of 11g).

[From the horses mouth](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/ds_concepts002.htm#i1108232):

> You cannot perform the following operations using database links:
>
> Grant privileges on remote objects
>
> Execute DESCRIBE operations on some remote objects. The following
>   remote objects, however, do support DESCRIBE operations:
>
> Tables Views Procedures Functions

**Analyze remote objects**

> Define or enforce referential integrity
>
> Grant roles to users in a remote database
>
> Obtain nondefault roles on a remote database. For example, if jane
>   connects to the local database and executes a stored procedure that
>   uses a fixed user link connecting as scott, jane receives scott's
>   default roles on the remote database. Jane cannot issue SET ROLE to
>   obtain a nondefault role.
>
> Execute hash query joins that use shared server connections
>
> Use a current user link without authentication through SSL, password,
>   or NT native authentication

Comment: Your assumption that a synonym is a "pointer" to something in a remote database via a database link is not entirely correct (or should I say complete). You can create a synonym for tables in your own schema or in another schema within the local database

Comment: @BobC Hi Bob, I was making that assumption based on the OPs statement "a synonym table means it point to another database".  I'm also guessing that English is not the poster's first language, so I'm trying to infer what I can from the post.